# Append scratch segment/curve on path

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pen-tool

While building paths on Photoshop, to append the next curve/segment, one can either click the canvas or click the canvas while holding Alt. Holding Alt will prevent curve based on the existing path.

Because my laptop's Alt is not working, how can I change the Alt key to some other key? Or yet better, can I disable the auto curve while building my path?

(I found no match for an Alt shortcut at the Keyboard Shortcuts.)

[image]

Comment: Not possible. Usually things like this are hardcoded in the tool sorry.

Comment: @jooja Animate CC allows to click instead, as a luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe it's possible to change the assignment/functionality of the Option/Alt key to another key. That's typically hard coded into the OS and apps use that designation, hardcoded as well.

You *can* break the auto-symmetry of smooth points though. It's a bit of a cumbersome workflow. Utilizing the Option/Alt key is much, much, easier and faster.

Simply switch to the **Convert Point Tool** and click-drag a handle, breaking the symmetry. Then switch back to the **Pen Tool** and keep drawing.

[image]

The path *should* remain active and "live" while doing this tool switching.

To speed this up, you can assign a shortcut to the Convert Point Tool (There isn't one by default). Simply choose `Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts > Shortcuts For: Tools` and scroll down until you see the Convert Point Tool.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use [AUTOHOTKEY](https://www.autohotkey.com/) to remap your ALT to another key like Caps:
First you could read documentation there, then you must install it, then use a script like this:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
#Persistent

#IfWinActive,ahk_class Photoshop
Capslock::Alt
```