# Break auto-symmetry with GIMP Paths Tool

Tags: gimp, path

This question is the same as [this one for Photoshop](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/136351), however using GIMP and the exception that my Alt key *is working*, however Alt does not work in GIMP like in Photoshop.

To quote the previous question, this is the problem (after adding a curve, the next path is curved as well):

[image]

Is there a way to resolve this in GIMP or is it esoteric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use a modifier key to do this in GIMP.

After clicking and dragging a curve, release the mouse button, then click and drag the Bézier handle to a new position, then continue with the tool.

Example

[image]

If you want to fully retract a Bézier handle, you can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+click on it

Example

[image]

Closing a path is achieved by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+clicking the first node you made.  After making a path everything is clickable and draggable: the handles themselves, and the actual path, and the nodes. If you want to re-smooth a node, hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> as you click and drag a handle.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> can also be used to delete nodes.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK no way to avoid this if you drag when doing the 2nd anchor, but you can always Ctrl-Shift-Click the extra tangent to remove it.